# In drupal, how we generate <form> tage with fapi

Tags: drupal, drupal-fapi

am using drupal, I made a form wiht drupal fapi

```
moduele_menu()
module_myform()
module_myform_submit
```

..

I get in my page the form elements ( inputs...) but i did not get the wrapper ( `<FORM action=...     </FORM>`!!!!

Can someone help please

Comment: please show us corresponding code

Comment: I think the mistake is in your menu item. Please post the code so we can fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `drupal_get_form('form_id')` to let drupal know about the form. That is what is creating the form HTML element and other elements needed by Drupal.